# Azure Pipeline Run Powershell MongoSH fail

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to create a database and collection in MongoDB with the Azure Pipeline
I created pipeline commands like this.
But
the use TESTDB command runs without waiting for the mongosh command to finish.
[image]
[image]

Comment: looks more like a compile issue.  look at your line 64, it is clearly saying, `use` is not valid.

Comment: @Greg mongosh isn't loaded correctly, therefore the "use" command can't be idetified or am I wrong?